# StyleCop formatting

Tags: c#, stylecop

How can I format the following line to eliminate StyleCop warnings:

```
this.BeginInvoke(this.updateHandler,new object[]{this.tmpbuf});
```

Now, I get 4 warnings:

- `Warning  4  SA1001: Invalid spacing around the comma.`
- `Warning  5  SA1011: Invalid spacing around the closing square bracket.`
- `Warning  6  SA1012: Invalid spacing around the opening curly bracket.`
- `Warning  7  SA1013: Invalid spacing around the closing curly bracket.`

Comment: CTRL+K followed by CTRL+D will fix the formatting for you in the current code file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Style Cop—what a joke. When I spell a word wrong, my spellchecker offers to correct it. It doesn't say 'invalid spelling' and leave me to guess.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
this.BeginInvoke(this.updateHandler, new object[] { this.tmpbuf });
```

- SA1001 requires space after a comma
- SA1011 requires space after closing square bracket
- SA1012 requires space after opening curly bracket
- SA1013 requires space before closing curly bracket

See [StyleCop spacing rules](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/spacingrules.htm) for full description of the relevant rules.

Comment: Link to style cop rules not valid anymore. Not layout rules can be found at http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/Layout%20Rules.html